# lldb error in console output and can't get correct result

Tags: ios, swift, lldb

My project code in here:

**[SMS_DEMO](https://github.com/renser/SMS_Demo)**

It runs successfully in Xcode but display (lldb) in console output, and error message

```
"thread 1:EXC_BREAKPOINT(code=EXC_I386_BPT,subcode=0x0",
```

Please kindly see below screen for details.

[image]

Could you please kindly help to see what I should do to solve this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Look at the left side where method calls are listed.(under network section). Click them in ascending order. Then you will see what method call causes the crash

Comment: Thanks for your comments, but sorry I still can't find the reason, could you please kindly show more details about this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked closely to image that you post. I suggest you to check the `getCo....` method from `ContactData` class. Inside it look for places where you cast a value. One of them is the source of this error.

#### EDIT: More Info

[image]

Here is the portion of your image that you should look. It show stack trace of thread 1 which is main thread. The number 0 line is where the crash happens. Looking the method name you can easily guess this is casting from one type to other. For example `let bar = baz as Bar`. Because of this cast failed your program crashed. Now the line 1 is your code. If you click that line you can see the line where the casting happens in editor.

Comment: Thanks! I looked for this place and see this code:
`phoneNumber = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty).takeRetainedValue() as NSString`
maybe the phone number is empty then cause this error, thank you.

Comment: for this code
`firstName = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty).takeRetainedValue() as NSString`
seems it will also cause crash if there is empty in FirstName field in my addressbook for some contacts.